# Not Being Indexed by Search Engines

Tags: seo, google-search, noindex

Is there a specific criteria based on which search engines index/not index your site/blog?

If my whole blog (2/3 pages-10-20 posts) is not indexed(WordPress), what can I do?

My blog has is not indexed by Google/Bing.
Any suggestions.

Comment: Try setting up your website on https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/ - you'll figure it out in no time.

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed that might effect this? Can you post your URL?

Comment: It's a blog. mydomain.wordpress.com No way plugins are installed.

Comment: We don't deal with `wordpress.com` support issues here, if this even has anything to do with WordPress at all. Sorry. But your robots.txt looks OK.

Comment: Ah. Ok. Thanks for info both about robots.txt and WordPress.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bit of a guess but there is a setting in the backend that will discourage indexing.

[image]

Make sure that is not checked.

Comment: Sadly no! But yes, it had to be guessed.